# Change :active pseudo-class' style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing some CSS editor and want to provide ability to change style for `<button>` when it's clicked. The following code doesn't change `background-color` to yellow.

http://jsfiddle.net/65erbrhh/

```
$('a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('button:active').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

**Edit: In my case, I can't assign specific class to a button, because it's user customizable html.**

Comment: So how do you deactivate a button in your case? css?

Comment: There is no need to deactivate, user can use same colors for `:active` state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't select elements based on their CSS state, one option would be to add a class to the element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w72a9r3/)

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('button').addClass('active-style');
});
```

```
button.active-style:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

But since you said you can't do that, you could alternatively attach an event listener for the `mousedown`/`mouseup` events and change the background color accordingly:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pw5wtzL/)

```
$('a').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('button').on('mousedown mouseup', function (e) {
        $(this).css('background-color', e.type === 'mousedown' ? 'yellow' : '');
    });
});
```

..but if you want the example to work if you `mouseup` *outside* of the `button` element, you would need to listen to *all* `mouseup` events:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9kzb3aa/)

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('button').addClass('active-style');
});

$(document).on('mousedown mouseup', function (e) {
    var color = (e.type === 'mousedown' && $(e.target).hasClass('active-style')) ? 'yellow' : '';
    $('button.active-style').css('background-color', color);
});
```

Comment: In your code you are targeting the `button` `on mouseup` and `on mouse down` while it's the `a` he wants.

Comment: This works for jsfiddle sample, however there is an interesting exception to that and I should have mentioned that in my OP. If I apply regular style for a `button` with jQuery, it ignores style specified in  general css definition. http://jsfiddle.net/feq71wdh/1/. That's non related issue, but it bugs me. =)

Comment: @AlexG Yeah, that's because jQuery's `.css()` method adds inline CSS, which always has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than CSS within a stylesheet.. (unless `!important` is used, which is discouraged.)

Comment: @JoshCrozier: implemented: `$(this).css('cssText', event.type === 'mousedown' ? cssProperty + ': ' + hex + ' !important' : '');` and it worked, except for 'border-color'. Do you know what could be an issue? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: nevermind, fixed by duplicating `border-width: 1px` in jQuery, apparently all previous properties are being ignored if I set 1 property with jQuery